# passing arguments like "process.argv[3]" to protractor using grunt-protractor-runner

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, protractor

I'm passing some arguments to protractor like `--chrome` and in protractor config, i use `process.argv[3]==--chrome` to pick up the required browser capabilities. Able to run that successfully using `protractor <config file> --chrome`

But when it comes to `grunt-protractor-runner`, I'm unable pass the argument.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use [grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) and be able to pass the arguments via the command line.

I use one to modify the browser

```
var browser = grunt.option('browser') || "" ;
```

and then we use [grunt-env](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env)

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    env : {
     options : { },
     prod : {
      TUNNEL : 0,
      BROWSER: browser,
      CUSTSUITE : custSuite,
      BROWSERSUITE: browserSuite,
      ENVIR : 'prod',
      SHARDS : shards,
      TAG : 'Prod',
      BUILD : build,
      OS : os

    },
   },

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');

  grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    'env:prod'
    ]);
```

in my conf.js we can access browser like this

```
if(process.env.BROWSER ==="ie"){
  exports.config.capabilities.browserName = 'internet explorer';
  exports.config.capabilities.version = '11';
  exports.config.seleniumAddress = 'http://ie11.dev:4444/wd/hub';
}
```

then my grunt command is like so

```
grunt prod --specs=tests/myspec.js --browser=ie
```

Comment: but in the config js file it says "Cannot read the property BROWSER" of undefined, can you post how your config.js is set?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add some information. You have to do grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env'); to load the module

and you have to register your task

Comment: i followed the same pattern you suggested, used grunt.registerTask('protractorTest', ['protractor:runProtractorTestSuite']); but in the config.js when i use if(process.protractor.browser.toUpperCase() === 'CHROME') it errors saying , Cannot read property 'browser' of undefined. do i have to reference this argument in the config?

Comment: if( process.env.BROWSER==="ie" || process.env.BROWSER==="firefox" || process.env.BROWSER==="chrome" || process.env.BROWSER==="safari") {
    exports.config.capabilities.browserName = process.env.BROWSER;
} else {
    // do something else
}

Comment: after creating a environmental variable in guntfile.js as process.env.BROWSER = grunt.option('BROWSER'); then process.env.BROWSER is working in protractor config